# count the number of members before group them

Tags: mongodb

here is my document:

```
member: [
    {
        name: 'Jack',
        group: 0
    },
    {
        name: 'Rose',
        group: 0
    },
    {
        name: 'Tom',
        group: 1
    }
]
```

first, count the number of members,then group them.

return：

```
{
    count: 3,
    member: [
        [
            {name: 'Jack'},
            {name: 'Rose'}
        ],
        [
            {name: 'Tom'}
        ]
    ]
}
```

how to do?thank you very much!

Comment: Do not you understand my question?

Comment: Yes I understand your question. Can you show me what you tried? your approach to solve this ?

Comment: @Yogesh i want to use the aggregate,but,i don't know how to return that result

Comment: i tried to use Project and Group, but, the result always likes [{name: 'Tom', count: 3}, {name: 'Jack', count: 3}] not {count: 3, members: [[{name: 'Tom'}, {name: 'Jack'}]]}

Comment: First you should check this **[$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/)**, **[$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) ** and **[$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)** try this if you not get output I will post my answer

Comment: yes, i have already used them.$size,$unwind and $group.
looking forward to your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should calculate `member` array size using `$size` in `$project`, after that `unwind` `member` and group them check below query :

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
    "$project": {
    "count": {
        "$size": "$member"
    },
    "member": 1
    }
}, {
    "$unwind": "$member"
}, {
    "$group": {
    "_id": "$member.group",
    "data": {
        "$push": {
            "name": "$member.name"
        }
    },
    "count": {
        "$first": "$count"
    }
    }
}, {
    "$group": {
    "_id": "$count",
    "member": {
        "$push": "$data"
    }
    }
}).pretty()
```

Comment: Aha!thank you! i forget the last $group,others is same to your codes